# Django save request.POST to JSONField picks last item from list instead of saving the list

Tags: python, json, django

I have a view that receives a post request from client.post()

```
        data = {
            "token": create_hash(customer_name),
            "images": [image_1, image_2],
            "name": customer_name,
            "email": "test@email.com",
            "phone": "0612345678",
            "product": "product-sku0",
            "font_family": "Helvetica",
            "font_size": 12,
            "colors_used": (
                "#AAAAAA|White D",
                "#FFFFFF|Black C"
            )
        }
```

I am trying to save the post request as a whole to a model.JSONfield().

The post request key-value pair looks like this:

```
'colors_used': ['#AAAAAA|White D', '#FFFFFF|Black C']
```

When I save and later retrieve the value it looks like this:

```
'colors_used': '#FFFFFF|Black C'
```

Instead of saving the nested list in the JSONfield it only saved the last value.

The view:

```
@csrf_exempt
def order(request):
    """
    Receives and saves request
    """

    post = request.POST
    files = request.FILES

    print(f"{post=}")

    assert post["token"] == create_hash(post["name"])

    design_obj = RequestDetails.objects.create(
        customer_name = post["name"],
        customer_email = post["email"],
        customer_phone = post["phone"],
        request_json = post
    )
```

I am using SQLite.

Comment: plz post your view

Comment: I have added the view to the post @Jonas

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is just default behaviour when you convert the queryset to a json string. On a key-level you can you getlist() to get all values of a multivalue key.

I ended up placing the whole nested data structure in a single json string using json.dumps(*data*) and just send that along with the request.